# How to pass an Object type to Type parameter in C#

Tags: c#, methods, types, parameters

I have a function that has Type Parameter.

```
public static object SetValuesToObject(Type tClass, DataRow dr)
{
   //
   .............
   //
   return object
}
```

I have no idea how to pass a class as parameter for this function.
Here i want to pass parmeter Class "Product".

I tried this

```
 SetValuesToObject(Product,datarow);
```

But it doesn't work. How could i do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`typeof` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/58918ffs.aspx) when you know the class at compile time.

```
SetValuesToObject(typeof(Product),datarow);
```

You can also use [`object.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) on instances that you don't know their type at compile time.

Comment: This saved me! You point out an important distinction about what's known at compile time and what's not. object.GetType() is what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few options:

1. `instance.GetType()` : this method (defined in Object) will return the instance's type.
2. `typeof(MyClass)` : will give you the type for a class.

Finally, if you own the method, you could change it to use Generics, and call it like this instead

`SetValuesToObject<Product>(datarow)`